# A-stability of a ODE system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

Look at the ODE

$$ y'=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} y$$

Let $y_i$ be the the numerical solution calculated by [Heun's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heun%27s_method). For which $h>0$ is $\|y_{i+1}\|_2 \leq \|y_i\|_2$?

I know that $R(z)=1+z+\frac{z^2}{2}$ ($z=\lambda h$) is the stability function of the scalar DE $y'=\lambda y$ and $|y_{i+1}|=|R(z)||y_i|$ in the scalar case. Any hints for this system?

Comment: Now insert $\lambda = \pm i$ and compute the norm of this complex number.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I started with $\|y_{i+1}\|_2=\sqrt{y_{1,i+1}^2+y_{2,i+1}^2}=\sqrt{R(-ih)^2y_{1,i}^2+R(ih)^2y_{2,i}^2 }=|R(-ih)| |y_{1,i}|+ |R(ih)| |y_{2,i}|$. Now I want that this is $\leq |y_{1,i}| +|y_{2,i}|$. Is this correct?

Comment: That last equality is wrong, and the norm definitions before are also wrong if you allow complex components. I was just hinting at $|R(\pm ih)|=\sqrt{1+h^4}>1$, the stability region does not include the imaginary axis.

Comment: In the one dimensional case I have $|y_{i+1}|=|R(z)||y_i|$. Is there a formula $\|y_{i+1}\|_2=...$ for a $n$-dimensional linear system?

Comment: @LutzLehmann why do you get $|R(ih)|=\sqrt{1+h^4}$? I get $|R(ih)|=\sqrt{1+\frac{h^4}{4}}$ and $|R(-ih)|=\sqrt{1-\frac{h^4}{4}}$

Comment: Yes, you are right and wrong. For some reason I missed the division by 4. You get always $i^4=1$, the second of your values should be equal to the first value.